# Positioning a div above an image inside of a bootstrap row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a div above an image. As you can see in the code below, there is the white square in the middle of the black div.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  /*  padding: 10px;*/
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999999999 !important;
  background-color: #000;
}

.itemimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 85px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg" class="itemimg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg" class="itemimg">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to put this black div above the white image. I have searched up solutions but they all use absolute and relative positioning. I have to keep the outer div relative or else the bootstrap grid system does not work. Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a `top` value of `150%`. This is the `100%` of the height of the `<div>`, plus `50%` to compensate for the `transform`.

Note that I've also added a border to illustrate this in the following example:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  /*  padding: 10px;*/
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999999999 !important;
  background-color: #000;
}

.itemimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 85px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg" class="itemimg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg" class="itemimg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TuckerRitti - You didn't once mention jQuery in your question, nor did you mention anything about an ID. And not being able to find an ID has **nothing** to do with where an element is located on the page. That's definitely an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378); something different to what you were initially asking for. I'd recommend asking a new question for that, specifically mentioning what you are **actually** trying to achieve. My answer shows how you can place the image below the `<div>`, which is **exactly** what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can not have a child element with `position` block or inline be beneath its own parent. You need to add a sibling `<div>` to the image.

I understand correctly you are looking to add an overlay over the image. Please see the update example with a red overlay that is over the image and the item. I also commented unnecessary CSS rules:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  /*  padding: 10px;*/
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*z-index: 999999999 !important;*/
  background-color: #000;
}

.itemimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 85px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg" class="itemimg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg" class="itemimg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, You don't want to show "White box" and that's why you are hiding behind "black box". If I am right, then why don't you use "left" position in negative range to hide it.

```css
    .item {
      position: relative;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
      /*  padding: 10px;*/
      margin: 10px 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 999999999 !important;
      background-color: #000;
    }

    .itemimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -500%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 85px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: -1651651651;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg" class="itemimg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg" class="itemimg">
  </div>
</div>
```